# await MessagingCenter in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to implement MVVM using MessagingCenter from my ViewModel.
I obtained the following error because multiples threads receive the same Message "ClearStackLayout" and don't wait the callback's end of each other :

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is my View code :

```
public partial class LibraryChoicePage : DefaultBackgroundPage {

        private Object thisLock = new Object();

        public LibraryChoicePage() {
            InitializeComponent();

            /* ClearStackLayout */
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LibraryChoiceViewModel>(this, "ClearStackLayout", (sender) => {
                lock (thisLock) {
                    this._choices.Children.Clear();
                }
            });

            /* AddToStackLayout */
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LibraryChoiceViewModel, View>(this, "AddToStackLayout", (sender, arg) => {
                lock (thisLock) {
                    this._choices.Children.Add(arg);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

The number one thing is ***always*** call `StackLayout.Children.Clear|Add` on the UI thread. *iOS does not like when removing `UIView` subviews off the main UI thread and will throw exceptions and can even cause native crashes*

This is how I would `serialized` the messaging calls:

```
var semaphone = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "ClearStackLayout",  async (sender) =>
{
    await semaphone.WaitAsync();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        _choices.Children.Clear();
    });
    semaphone.Release();
});

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, View>(this, "AddToStackLayout", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await semaphone.WaitAsync();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        _choices.Children.Add(arg);
    });
    semaphone.Release();
});
```

*Note: `try/finally` should be wrapping the `SemaphoreSlim.Release` and a `catch` to execute any recoverer code needed from add/clear failures.*

UIUnit Parallel Test Method:

```
Random random = new Random();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    if (random.NextDouble() > .1)
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { AddLayout(); }));
    else
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ClearLayout(); }));
}
var completed = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), (messagecenterTasks) => { 
    foreach (var task in messagecenterTasks)
    {
        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
        {
            D.WriteLine("Faulted:");
            D.WriteLine($"  {task.Exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}).Wait(1000);
if (!completed)
    D.WriteLine("Some tasks did not complete in time allocated");
```

*Note: AddLayout/ClearLayout are method wrappers for the `MessageCenter.Send` of `AddToStackLayout` and `ClearStackLayout`.*